# Customize Paypal checkout page

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

using PHP REST API SDK, is there a way to customize the first PayPal page that appears (login page) when doing a Payment.  Specifically, we would like to move "Pay with Debit or Credit Card" above and make larger than "Pay with Paypal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to edit any portion of the hosted secure checkout page of PayPal standard or PayPal Express Checkout. The only change you 'can' make is add a logo or header image that populates and replaces the business name or email to the account.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought, but my boss doesn't believe me

Comment: how about getting the "Pay with Debit or Credit Card" page to appear first before a PayPal login?

Comment: You can do that and invoke the credit card fields of the paypal checkout by sending landingpage=billing solutiontype=sole in your payment request. Sure, can be done